# how to implement spring feign post and delete

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I build a spring cloud service ,contains eureka, user-service(spring-data-rest user api) and a feign-client service .

In the feign client :

```
@FeignClient("useraccount")
public interface UserFeign {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/users",consumes = "application/json")
    void createUser(@RequestBody User user);
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE,value="/users/{id}")
    void delById (@PathVariable("id") String id);
```

I want to implement  removing and storing users in feign-client  by calling user-service api . So , i create a rest controller (js Transfer data to them) :

```
@Autowired
    private UserFeign userFeign;

//save controller 

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/property/register")
    public  ResponseEntity<?>  createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
            userSaveFeign.createUser(user);
            return   ResponseEntity.ok();
    }


// and delete controller 

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/property/{id}")
    public String hello(@PathVariable("id") String id){
            userSaveFeign.delById(id);
        }
        return "hello";
    }
```

but it always met errors :

```
2016-04-16 20:05:41.162   .DynamicServerListLoadBalancer     DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client useraccount initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=useraccount,current list of Servers=[192.168.1.101:useraccount:d3fb971b6fe30dc5e9cbfdf0e713cd12],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;  Instance count:1;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:192.168.1.101:useraccount:d3fb971b6fe30dc5e9cbfdf0e713cd12;    Zone:defaultZone;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@19c54b19
2016-04-16 20:05:41.836[2m[nio-8002-exec-4][36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]  [0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: createUser timed-out and no fallback available.] with root cause

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:600) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:580) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:99) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:955) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:972) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

Maybe  the above store and delete method have problems ,but who can tell me the right or better ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your Hystrix Command is timing out. Assuming you don't specifically have any Hystrix Commands (as not mentioned in your post), Hystrix is a circuit breaker technology that is included free with Feign Client. You can disable this with:

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=false
```

(And you can find more information about Feign-Hystrix integration at http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#spring-cloud-feign-hystrix)

This won't address the route cause that something is taking a long time to complete. You will need to debug and find out whats hanging. It could be the actual endpoint your Feign client is pointed at is connecting but is not responsive, although I would usually expect to see a specific connection timeout exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the actual exception, you should find the reason why its timedout. Enable logging, then you can see why it is failing:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import feign.Logger;

public class FeignConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }
}
```

Also look if the server is resolved at all. Your log should have something like below:

```
DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client auth-service initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=auth-service,current list of Servers=[192.168.2.243:7277],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone; Instance count:1;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:192.168.2.243:8180;    Zone:defaultZone;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 06:00:00 BDT 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 06:00:00 BDT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@9481a7c
```